# CSV delimiter doesn't work properly [Python]

Tags: python, csv

```
import csv

base='eest1@mail.ru,username1\
test2@gmail.com,username2\
test3@gmail.com,username3\
test4@rambler.ru,username4\
test5@ya.ru,username5'

parsed=csv.reader(base, delimiter=',')
for p in parsed:
    print p
```

Returns:

```
['e']
['e']
['s']
['t']
['1']
['@']
['m']
['a']
['i']
['l']
['.']
['r']
['u']
['', '']
```

etc...

How I can get data separated by comma ?
('test1@gmail.com', 'username1'),
('test2@gmail.com', 'username2'),
...

Answer (score 2):

I think csv only works with file like objects.  You can use StringIO in this case.

```
import csv
import StringIO

base='''eest1@mail.ru,username
test2@gmail.com,username2
test3@gmail.com,username3
test4@rambler.ru,username4
test5@ya.ru,username5'''

parsed=csv.reader(StringIO.StringIO(base), delimiter=',')
for p in parsed:
    print p
```

OUTPUT

```
['eest1@mail.ru', 'username']
['test2@gmail.com', 'username2']
['test3@gmail.com', 'username3']
['test4@rambler.ru', 'username4']
['test5@ya.ru', 'username5']
```

Also, your example string does not have newlines, so you would get

```
['eest1@mail.ru', 'usernametest2@gmail.com', 'username2test3@gmail.com', 'username3test4@rambler.ru', 'username4test5@ya.ru', 'username5']
```

You can use the `'''` like I did, or change your `base` like

```
base='eest1@mail.ru,username\n\
test2@gmail.com,username2\n\
test3@gmail.com,username3\n\
test4@rambler.ru,username4\n\
test5@ya.ru,username5'
```

**EDIT**
According to the docs, the argument can be either a file-like objet OR a list.  So this works too

```
parsed=csv.reader(base.splitlines(), delimiter=',')
```

Answer (score 1):

Quoting [official docs on csv module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.reader) (**emphasis mine**):

> `csv.reader(csvfile, dialect='excel', **fmtparams)`
>
> Return a reader object which will iterate over lines in the given
>   `csvfile`. **`csvfile` can be any object which supports the iterator
>   protocol and returns a string each time its `__next__()` method is
>   called — file objects and list objects are both suitable.**

Strings supports iterator, but it yields *characters* from string one by one, not lines from multi-line string.

```
>>> s = "abcdef"
>>> i = iter(s)
>>> next(i)
'a'
>>> next(i)
'b'
>>> next(i)
'c'
```

So the task is to create iterator, which would yield *lines* and not *characters* on each iterations. Unfortunately, your string literal is not a multiline string.

```
base='eest1@mail.ru,username1\
test2@gmail.com,username2\
test3@gmail.com,username3\
test4@rambler.ru,username4\
test5@ya.ru,username5'
```

is equivalent to:

```
base = 'eest1@mail.ru,username1test2@gmail.com,username2test3@gmail.com,username3test4@rambler.ru,username4test5@ya.ru,username5
```

Esentially you do not have information required to parse that string correctly. Try using multiline string literal instead:

```
base='''eest1@mail.ru,username1
test2@gmail.com,username2
test3@gmail.com,username3
test4@rambler.ru,username4
test5@ya.ru,username5'''
```

After this change you may split your string by newlines characters and everything should work fine:

```
parsed=csv.reader(base.splitlines(), delimiter=',')
for p in parsed:
    print(p)
```